# In a VS 2015 extension, how can I get the selected object in the Solution Explorer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, visual-studio-2015, vsix

I'm interested in getting a Project or ProjectItem (as examples, not limited to those two) for the current selection where only a single item is selected.

Most people seem to be using `IVsMonitorSelection` to get an `IVSHierarchy` and then use the following to get the object for the selected item (in case of a single item being selected):

```
var monitorSelection = (IVsMonitorSelection) Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(IVsMonitorSelection));

IntPtr hierarchyPointer, selectionContainerPointer;
uint projectItemId;
IVsMultiItemSelect multiItemSelect;

monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection(out hierarchyPointer, out projectItemId, out multiItemSelect, out selectionContainerPointer);

var hierarchy = (IVsHierarchy) Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(hierarchyPointer);

Marshal.Release(hierarchyPointer);
Marshal.Release(selectionContainerPointer);

object o;

hierarchy.GetProperty((uint) projectItemId, (int) __VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject, out o);
```

However, `GetProperty` returns E_NOTIMPL here. Am I using the wrong parameters? Is there an alternative solution perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer from Sergey, I found dte.SelectedItems, which is even "more strongly-typed" and does not require casting to an array containing UIHierarchy
items.

The result is now:

`dte.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem`

Answer (score 5):

You can use **dte.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer.SelectedItems** like this:

```
EnvDTE.ProjectItem projectItem = GetSelectedSolutionExplorerItem().Object as EnvDTE.ProjectItem;

    private EnvDTE.UIHierarchyItem GetSelectedSolutionExplorerItem()
    {
        EnvDTE.UIHierarchy solutionExplorer = dte.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer;
        object[] items = solutionExplorer.SelectedItems as object[];
        if (items.Length != 1)
            return null;

        return items[0] as EnvDTE.UIHierarchyItem;
    }
```

Comment: This is so much simpler and it works like a charm! Thank you, this has resolved my issue.