# How to select icon for customized menu entry in VisualStudio?

Tags: debugging, karma-runner

I use a custom command (external tool command) as entry for the Item context menu of the SolutionExplorer. How can I assign an icon to my custom command?

I am able to choose the name of the command using "Modify Selection" and I am able to select the option "Image and Text". However, I did not find an option to choose the icon that should be used for my customized menu entry.

Related question:
[How to execute custom file specific command / task in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321194/how-to-execute-custom-file-specific-command-task-in-visual-studio)