# Add icon to existing menu command in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

*Disclaimer*: this is about using Visual Studio and its GUI. It is **not** about a VS extension.

Context:

I like to have toolbar buttons to sort and remove `using` directives in `.cs` files. In VS 2015 there were two dedicated commands (and hence buttons) to do this, each with their own icon. Now in VS 2017 there's a single command to do that (*Remove and Sort Usings*) but it has no icon, just text. See pciture below, command is there, but text only:

[image]

I remember ages ago, with VS 2010 I believe, you could somehow hack VS existing commands so to show custom icons. I think it was a matter of adding picture files in a special location, and either name them in a special way or reference them from some configuration file. I totally forgot how, but it was doable.

Question:

Does anyone know if this is still possible with VS 2017 and how? After some search I was not able to find an answer.

BTW question is similar to [this unanswered one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353364/how-to-select-icon-for-customized-menu-entry-in-visualstudio), but in my case it's about a regular VS command, not an external tool command.

TA

**Edit:** as suggested in comments, this [CommandingImage extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.CommandingImage) used to work on VS 2010. It has not been updated, nor open-sourced, nor ported. Maybe someone as found its successor.

Comment: VS2008 was the last version that support this out of the box, the feature was lost in the WPF rewrite at VS2010.  Lots of complaints about it, so a team member wrote [an extension](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/06/17/command-image-changing-extension/) to get the feature back.  Bad links in the blog post, I think it is [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.CommandingImage).  But not very popular and not maintained, back to square one.  I see other ones in the gallery, can't judge their quality.

Comment: Oh, after visiting the blog post I remember also having used that one to set icons!

Comment: Be sure to note it in your question, you'll want an answer from somebody that used it as well and figured out which alternative works well in VS2017.

Answer (score 7):

With Visual Studio 2017, it can be done using [Visual Studio SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-studio-sdk) where you can either write a extension or extend a existing menu command with a icon declared in the [.vsct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-menus-and-commands) file. A simple example for the your need can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-icons-to-menu-commands).

If you want to go for a simpler way, I would suggest to either use [PowerCommands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.PowerCommandsforVisualStudio) or Resharper to do the same. See [here](https://drewsheneman.com/2017/08/06/automatically-remove-and-sort-usings-on-save-in-visual-studio-2017/).

Comment: There are like 3-5 productivity tools (easy-finds) that can accomplish this task. Those mentioned above and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017, and there are more. I'd go with that one too.

Comment: I do have Power Commands extension but that does not fulfil what I'm looking for. I'm not sure I'm on the same track: it is not a matter of showing the Remove/Sort Using command in toolbar. That is doable already. I'm looking for a way to associate an icon to that command. I think I'll add a picture. The https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-icons-to-menu-commands link about custom extensions can go in the right (although long) direction.

Comment: @Robionic do you know how to create such an extension, that only customizes appearance for an existing menu command? Would you like to expand your answer on that? Thanks