# Implementing new icons for built-in commands

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, toolbar, visual-studio-extensions

How can I write an extension to replace the icon for a built-in Visual Studio command (eg: Edit → Copy)?
Similarly how can I add an icon for a built-in command that doesn't have one (eg: File → Close)?

An answer to [Add icon to existing menu command in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120238/add-icon-to-existing-menu-command-in-visual-studio-2017/50235829#50235829) indicates using an extension is the way to go, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

I've used the standard C# VSIX Project template and added a new custom Command.
To this I've added...

```
<!-- A toolbar -->
<Menus>
  <Menu guid="guidVSIXProject1PackageCmdSet" id="ToolbarID" type="Toolbar">
    <CommandFlag>DefaultDocked</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>Test bar</ButtonText>
      <CommandName>TestBar</CommandName>
    </Strings>
  </Menu>
</Menus>

<!-- A toolbar group -->
<Groups>
  <Group guid="guidVSIXProject1PackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
  </Group>
  <Group guid="guidVSIXProject1PackageCmdSet" id="ToolbarGroupID" priority="0x0000">
    <Parent guid="guidVSIXProject1PackageCmdSet" id="ToolbarID" />
  </Group>
</Groups>
...
<!-- A button -->
  <Button guid="guidVSStd97" id="cmdidCopy" priority="0x0300" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidVSIXProject1PackageCmdSet" id="ToolbarGroupID" />
    <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic2" />
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>TestCopy</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>

...
<!-- This doesn't seem to do anything -->
<UsedCommands>
  <UsedCommand guid="guidVSStd97" id="cmdidCopy"/>
</UsedCommands>
```

I got `cmdidCopy` from VsDbgCmdPlace.VSCT under `<Visual Studio SDK installation path>` as documented in
[GUIDs and IDs of Visual Studio commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-commands). It appears on the toolbar & works, but with the original icon.
Weirdly, in the toolbar Customize dialog the new icon appears but not the new text!
[image: Toolbar customize dialog]

Reason for question: VS icons are limited to miserly 16px and the stock icons are often hard for me to distinguish.

Edit: Still an issue in VS 2022 (v17.1.0). [VSIX Community Toolkit discussion](https://github.com/VsixCommunity/Community.VisualStudio.Toolkit/discussions/298)

Comment: Please try to delete `C:\Users\xxx(current user account)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxExp\1033\devenv.CTM` and then debug your vsix project again.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT It didn't help unfortunately. I even removed the whole VisualStudio folder in both local & roaming AppData.